# Раскопировать html документ с изменениями NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js

Здравствуйте, уважаемые разрабы. Я в этом деле совсем новичок.

**Проблема:** Есть список городов, примерно 250. Сейчас на яндекс.вебмастер 250 лендингов, в которых изменяется только город в одном месте и настроена региональность для `SEO` выдачи. При изменениях на сайте приходится повторять ужасную процедуру копирования файлов и изменения в одном `span` с названием соответствующего Города - Мск, Питер, Екатеринбург и т.д.

**Вопрос:** Как это реализовать эту процедуру на `NodeJs`? Пытался накопать информацию, остановился на `fs.open`, `fs.append` и т.д.. Может кто-то поделиться кодом решения? Была ли у кого-нибудь такая проблема?

Comment: Выложите код, что Вы пробовали сделать?

Comment: Для работы с файлами смотрите документацию [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).  
Для замены строк можно использовать [str.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) и/или [регулярки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0):

Если этот *span* можно однозначно выцепить с помощью ***jQuery*** то можно это сделать с помощью [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался, если это кому-то пригодится:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
fs = require('fs'),
iconvlite = require('iconv-lite');
fs.readFile('index.php', "utf-8", dataLoaded); //считываем нужный файл с 
callback
var arr = [["Абдулино", "Абдулино"],
    ["Айхале", "Айхал"]]; //здесь массив городов в нужных для задачи падежах
    function dataLoaded(err, data) {
      if (err) {
           if (err.code == 'ENOENT') {
        console.error(err.message);
      } else {
           console.error(err);
      }
   }
   else{
    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++){
        console.log("File is read.............................");
        $ = cheerio.load('' + data + '', { decodeEntities: false }); //помещаем все в черио 
        console.log("Data loaded..............................");
        $("title").append(arr[i][0]); //производим необходимые замены
        $(".changeCityHeader").append(arr[i][0]); 
        $(".changeCityFooter").append(arr[i][1]);
        console.log("Sity is added............................");
        console.log('Text in title is: ' + $("title").text());
        console.log('Text in header is: ' + $(".changeCityHeader").text());
        console.log('Text in footer is: ' + $(".changeCityFooter").text());


        var content = $.html();
            filename = "new-files/"+ arr[i][0] + "-index" + ".php";
        fs.writeFile(filename, content, "utf-8", function(err) {

        }); //изменения записываем в новый файл с изменениями
        console.log('Written html to ' + filename + "...........................");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Может быть не самый лучший способ, однако теперь не трачу на это время.